# how to get HTTP response headers and body after POST request using curl

Tags: http, http-headers, http-post, libcurl

```
static size_t write_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
    {
        int totalSize = size*nmemb;
        if(totalSize > 1)
        {
            strncpy((char*)userp,(char*)ptr,totalSize);
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &this->responseData);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION ,write_callback);
```

how to get header response  and body in write_callback function ?

I have to print like this form.

response header : 200
body : error-too big.

Answer (score 4):

You can get response header if you use `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1)`.

But the `write_callback` may be called many times

Just try this.

curl_test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

size_t write_func(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
        //write(STDOUT_FILENO, ptr, size*nmemb); 
        printf("write_func\n");
        return size * nmemb;
}

int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
        CURL *curl;
        if (argv != 2) {
                return 0;
        }
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (!curl) {
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_init error");
        }
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, argc[1]);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_func);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return 0;
}
```

cmd:

```
gcc curl_test.c -o curl_test -lcurl && ./curl_test www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow the official libcurl guide you want to do:

```c
/* send all data to this function  */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, cb);

/* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
```

With:

```c
struct memory {
    char *response;
    size_t size;
};

static size_t cb(void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct memory *mem = (struct memory *)userp;

    char *ptr = realloc(mem->response, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if(ptr == NULL)
        return 0;  /* out of memory! */

    mem->response = ptr;
    memcpy(&(mem->response[mem->size]), data, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->response[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}

struct memory chunk;
```

Reference: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html